# Sync application data to different android device

Tags: android, synchronization

Hello Friends i want to sync my whole application data to different - different device like

i have `Samsung` device at first time i install my application on it and i store some data on it but i have another device like `HTC` or `Samsung` and i want my previous data which i store in my `Previous Samsung device` it should be show me in my new Device so how can i Sync my application data  is there any way for the please suggest any link or code for that ?

Comment: Have you thought about using an online database?

Comment: @epsilondelta:: I want to sync data with my local database i dont want to sync with web service so is there any way without web service we can sync application data to different devices?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these articles on the android dev site.

**Backup API**
http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html

**Sync Adapters**
http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html